# Is there any way to make white backgrounds dark besides inverting?

Tags: laptop, colors

For example, when I just google something or even here on stackexchange.com or reddit.com (or youtube, most any website really), everybody insists on making the background completely white, which is really harsh at night sometimes. I was just wondering if there is an option out there somewhere (even if only for select websites) to always keep the background black and just the text / images / videos white.

You'd think the websites would give you an option to choose the background color you want, but they don't. I would think it wouldn't be that difficult to implement. Just make everything with black text white, put white borders on black boxes (so they don't blend in with the black background), and leave the rest.  Obviously inverting the colors works sometimes, but not always.  I'm not looking for something that makes *everything* darker (I actually have f.lux installed already).  Just seems like there would be a way to make website (or even everything on your laptop) backgrounds dark / black (I have Windows 7 myself).  Thanks.

Comment: Look at using a dark theme.  For your browser, look at the Stylish add-on.

Comment: You're amazing.  I just go to "Find more styles for this site" or could even create my own for any site, much easier on the eyes.  Thank you!!  Now I wonder if there's a way to give OS things a darker background (like My Pictures).

Comment: For the OS, just Google "Windows 7 dark theme" for links like this: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-dark-windows-themes-skins-reduce-eye-strain/